# Strange NTFS Partition, Seemingly Created by Windows 10 Update?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

So I used to have a partition mounted as F:, and it was my old Mac's hard drive (Disk3 in the screenshot below) using a a free HFS+ driver I found when running Windows 8. I've never been able to mount that partition since updating to Windows 10, so naturally haven't seen that drive letter in a while.

Recently however, I started getting windows popups about disk F: having low space... this was news since it's not supposed to be there, but it turns out that there's a 450MB partition on my main SSD that's being mounted as F:, and I swear I'd never noticed it prior to this behaviour. What's even more odd is that if I right-click on it in Disk Management the only option is "Help...", i.e. I can't change drive letter assignments etc.

Does anybody know if a recent update would have introduced this, and whether or not I can safely delete it?

[image: Disk management showing the new partition]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a recovery partition. Windows installer and updates create it when there's not enough space on the original partition. It shouldn't have a drive letter assigned by default.

It's generally not safe to delete. Windows will stop you from modifying this partition from UI by disabling context menu items.

If you want to sacrifice OS recoverability for disk space, you can disable recovery using `reagentc.exe` and delete the partition with `diskpart`.

#### How to remote the drive letter:

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, type `diskpart` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Confirm running `diskpart` if asked.
2. Type `list volume` and confirm it with <kbd>Enter</kbd> (all commands onwards are confirmed with <kbd>Enter</kbd>). A list of volumes will be printed to the console.
3. Identify the recovery partition by the letter in the second column. Take note of its number in the first column.
4. Use the command `select volume <NUM>` to select recovery partition. Substitute `<NUM>` with appropriate number from previous step.
5. Issue the command `remove all` to remove drive letter. *This will NOT remove the partition, just the letter!*
6. Finally, use command `exit` to quit `diskpart`.

Comment: I've seen it happen that the partition is made, a driveletter is assigned, Explorer notifies the user, then the driveletter is removed. I'd call it a bug in the update process.

Comment: I don't need the space, but I'd like to remove the drive letter somehow. I saw you can disable the low space warnings through a registry change, but then I'd lose them for all drives.

Comment: @MattLacey The driveletter should be already gone. Just reboot if things are not working correctly, and the driveletter should be gone visually as well.

Comment: @LPChip Nah, it's been there for a few days now, across reboots. The low space warnings finally drove me over the edge tonight!

Comment: What you can’t do from the GUI you can do from `diskpart` you can unassign a drive letter or delete the partition from there.

Comment: @MattLacey is there an option from the GUI to ADD a driveletter? it may work if you add the letter then remove it.

Comment: @LPChip No option :(

Comment: @gronostaj So I was premature in accepting. A reboot later, and the it's back, complete with low space warnings!

Comment: @Matt Wow, that's weird. I have no idea why would that happen.