# EFI partition appearing after factory mode

Tags: windows-10, efi

When I reset my Windows 10 to factory mode, a new partition showed up; it's an EFI partition.  It's my new laptop and I am concerned about whether that could cause any problem.  delete files in the future or damage hard disk.

Comment: Your question is unintelliginble. What's your question? What kind of problem are you experiencing? Were you doing anything that resulted in this issue? Please [edit] your question to add this information. Try to use proper English and don't make everything bold.

Comment: I did a little cleanup, but I didn't understand the last sentence.  Can you add detail about exactly what you did, what partition you're referring to, and what you're worried about?

Comment: after re-installing Win 10  EFI partition showing up as z:local disk

Comment: my question is why this partition appears after reinstalling win 10 .. is this bad

Comment: i am new in this site i dont know how to ask,,, and my english  bad

Comment: Okay, so you have reinstalled Windows 10 and now the EFI System Partition appears in Explorer with letter `Z:`. Is that correct?

Comment: @waleed. That's normal if you install Windows on UEFI mode instead of legacy BIOS mode.

Comment: that what i want to know ... thank u so much for ur help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't cause problem. If you install Windows 10 on UEFI mode instead of legacy BIOS mode, it will generate a EFI partition.

Comment: But you can and should remove the driver letter. The EFI partition should not be exposed to users, it just stores the bootloaders.

Comment: really!! do u know how to do it ?

Comment: @waleed Use these instructions: https://superuser.com/a/1315421/194694